# Unable to add Facebook channel to Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: facebook, azure, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I am unable to add Facebook Messenger as a channel to my bot. I'm receiving 400 error in the console and a fairly arcane error message (see the attached image). I have been able to successfully add DirectLine, Skype, and Slack.

From a troubleshooting perspective, I've tried the following:

- Create a new bot and try adding Facebook Messenger
- Create a new Facebook App
- Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all in regular and incognito modes
- Create a bot using a different Azure and Bot Framework account and a different Facebook account

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Comment: Did you configure your webhooks between Facebook and Bot framework channel ?

Comment: @BobSwager Yes I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the root issue here. The person who created the Facebook App did not associated it with a Facebook Page and generate the requisite Page Access Token. Once this was completed adding the Facebook Messenger channel worked correctly.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction [Bob Swager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7739945/bob-swager)!

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)